# Can't refresh external connection in Excel from Mac

Tags: excel, macos, powerquery

I have an Excel workbook that has several External data connections via PowerQuery (actually from built-in Data > Get External Data, and slightly modified code in PowerQuery to include variable filenames). The connections are made to .xslx, .xlsm and .csv files.

As I read, Microsoft states that it is possible to refresh existing connections on Mac, that are made to these types of files (not sure about .xlsm, but probably that does not matter, as not a single connection refreshes). However, when I try to refresh a query, it throws an error:

```
[Expression.Error] The module named 'ExcelInterop' has been disabled in this context.
```

At first, I thought it was a connection to Named Table in the current workbook (as I read on Microsoft, it is not supported in Mac), but even when I removed it, the problem persisted. There is not really much information on Google on this issue, so I post it here. Is there a way to actually refresh the data on Mac or no? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I have an .xlsx workbook which is connected through PowerQuery to other .csv and .xlsx files.

When External Data sources are updated and I need to refresh the main workbook with those new data, I just press *"Refresh All"* in the *"Data"* Tab and get no error message.

It's the button with the green arrows:

[image: button with green arrows]

I have Excel v. 16.83 installed on macOS Ventura

If for some reason you have less powerQuery functionality or don't see the *"Refresh All"* button try:

- *Check Updates* (under "?" in macOS tab) -> *Advanced*
- Select *"Beta"* as update channel.

If I didn't understand your problem, it would be great if you could post a screenshot of the error message.